# Prove that for every positive integer, this polynomial is divisible by 8

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

prove that: $$8\mid (n-1)n(n+1)(n+2)$$

I tried to simplify this expression but had no luck.

Comment: Among four consecutive integers, one is divisible by $4$, and another is divisble by $2$, hence the product is divisible by $8$.

Comment: Of course you had no luck in *simplifying*. That's not possible here.

Comment: hi thanks for all the answers i finally resolved the problem in this question can you please close my question

Answer (score 2):

With four consecutive numbers, you can write them like $4m, 4m+1, 4m+2, 4m+3$ (or possibly a shifted version of this like $4m-1, 4m, 4m+1, 4m+2$). In any case, taking four consecutive natural numbers, one of them is divisible by $4$ and a separate one is divisible by $2$. Thus the product is divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

prove that of $4$ consecutive numbers at least one is a multiple of $4$, and that one of the others is a multiple of $2$.

Comment: i know that (n-1)n is divisible by 2. but why (n+1)(n+2) is divisible by 4?

Comment: you have to consider the cases $$n\equiv 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\mod 8$$

Comment: @AlonBerman What's the difference between consecutive multiples of $4$?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Actually, no. Mod 4 is enough.

Comment: Can you prove that at least one of $n-1,n,n+1,n+2$ is a multiple of $4$? If e.g. $4|n$ then $2|n+2$ and you are ready. Also in the other cases there is a way out.

Comment: but $\mod 8$ is also possible

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes, possible. But let's keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For an integer $n>1$ the number $${n+2\choose 4}$$ is an integer, we recognize that
$$3{n+2\choose 4}=3\cdot\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)}{4!}=\frac{(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)}8$$
Hence $(n+2)(n+1)n(n-1)$ is a multiple of $8$.